# Can you enter Yosemite on the 2nd day of a 3-day pass?

Tags: covid-19, yosemite

The [website](https://www.recreation.gov/timed-entry/10086745/ticket/10086746) says "Your reservation is valid for 3 consecutive days, beginning the day of arrival reserved."

What it doesn't say is whether it still remains valid for two more days if I don't use it on the first valid day.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  In 2021, the pass is valid for entry on any (or all) of the 3 days that it  is valid for.  There is no need to enter on the first day of the pass.

The rules were different in 2020, and at that time you did have to enter on the first day (and could then re-enter on the remaining dates, but only if you had entered on the first day) so you may still find references to that requirement, but it is NOT correct for 2021.

Comment: Do you or anyone else have a link to the source? I trust your answer but I'd like to bring a printout of the rule with me just in case the ranger doesn't know.

Comment: It's on the NPS website page which is linked from the page you included in your original question, but the staff at the entrance booths are very aware of the rules and you will absolutely not have any issues entering.